# Directory location of the Geary Mail Client toolbar icons in Elementary OS?

Tags: elementary-os, theme, icons, geary

Where are located the icons for the Geary toolbar used by the elementary iconset? I now use use the Faba-mono icons but a few are missing and I want to add them.

With elementary icon set the toolbar looks like so:

[image]

With Faba-mono:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Faba-mono theme is missing some action icons, you can find them in `[your theme-drecory]/actions`.

In your case the theme is missing `edit-flag.svg`, `mail-move.svg`, `tag-new.svg` and `mail-archive.svg`. The correct icon-size should be 24px.

If you want to add the elementary-icons into Faba, you could let Faba inherit the elementary-theme instead of copying them by hand.
Just add `'elementary'` to the line `Inherits=[...]` in the `index.theme` of Faba.

Comment: I got a also a comment under [HERE](https://plus.google.com/+CipricusCipriq/posts/f9kKdPVLx2x) saying to just set faba-mono to inherit from elementary. But what that does is that it just replaces almost completely Faba-mono with elementary icons, especially the file manager (after that only the dock uses faba-mono). As you said, **not faba-mono, but faba has to inherit elementary**